# How to execute Scrapy and Selenium on the page which serves data from angular JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, scrapy

I am making a scraper which works in something like this ->

Visit the site A --> clicks on the buy now button --> lands on Amazon --> scrape data --> back to the site A

Problem is that site is made on AnugularJS. I am unable to click the button with selenium.click()

I am using selenium and scrapy to scrape this javascript page.
The page is infinite loading page kindly suggest a solution which works for the infinite loading page.

Here is the Div element -

```
<a class="external" href="http://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DBR53FU/?tag=097-20&amp;ascsubtag=v7_3_3_3m7_2nhz_0_x01_-srt5-" target="_blank" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="button" analytics-category="outbound" analytics-label="non-lethal-salt-firing-self-defense-gun" ng-click="click(post)" rel="nofollow">Check it out </a>
```

The syntax I tried was,

```
 sel.xpath('//*[@class="button"]').click()
```

Which returns,

```
'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Comment: What is the language binding that you're using-Python or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'click'
```

means that the `click` method will not work on the element returned by your xpath.

Try this - in Python

```
    element_to_click = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.external')
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element_to_click)
    element_to_click.click()
```

or

```
element_to_click = 

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DBR53FU/?tag=097-20&amp;ascsubtag=v7_3_3_3m7_2nhz_0_x01_-srt5-')]")
#assuming that the href doesn't change.  


driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element_to_click) 



# scroll element into view   

element_to_click.click()
```

or

you can use the linkText as mentioned by the other answer.

Edit 3: Try sending a JS click to this locator

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element_to_click)
```

Edit 4 : See this edit carefully. Clicking on any gift item on this page is very easy

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_path  = 'your chromedriver path here'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("http://thisiswhyimbroke.com/gifts/gifts-for-men/")
time.sleep(5)

#clicks on the first gift article
first_article = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#page-gifts > article:nth-child(1) > div.button > a')
first_article.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

All the gift article mentioned are generated by a `repeater` since this is an Angular web page. All the gift's that are shown are present inside an `article` tag.

If you want to click on the second or third or any other article button, you just have to change the `article:nth-child` to get the corresponding child and this code would work.

Before you start automation, please have a brief reading about how you can create, use locators before diving into automation.

Comment: `element_to_click.click()` gives this error - `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a class="external" href=""> could not be scrolled into view`

Comment: Sorry to say, Sir it still gives the same error `Element <a class="external" href=""> could not be scrolled into view`

Comment: Sir any Idea why am I not able to click the button?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.external')` gives this message `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="be6a6535-7db8-46fa-8a4d-c4ac0b5fe04b", element="0f310fae-ae2e-4987-a5c2-bbae575acd2c")>` I can't understand this JS pages

Comment: see Edit 3 in the answer

Comment: Great this worked sir but instead of landing in amazon it redirects to the homepage, the page has many check it out button all targetting Amazon but still it redirects to the homepage here is the url please have a look https://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com/gifts/gifts-for-men/

Comment: Please first understand the structure of the page you're automating then try to automate it. Also this comment is out of scope of this question. I can give you the code for clicking the link but what will be your learning in that?

Comment: See my final edit - you can use this to click on any gift article button

Comment: Thank you, sir I am looking at this btw can you tell what does this stands for? - arguments[0]

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-argument-0-and-argument-1-mean-in-javascriptexecutor-in-Selenium-WebDriver

Comment: Thankyou so much Sir I was depressed for this from last week. Can you give me some resources where I can Learn more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either CSS Selector which is

```
".external"
```

or by using Link Text which is

```
"Check it out"
```

Comment: Problem is arising for clicking

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you use these "with click"?

Comment: this one sir `Element <a class="external" href=""> could not be scrolled into view`

Comment: which browser and driver version you're using ?

Comment: Sir Firefox Browser

Comment: I am asking you version numbers of both browser and driver

Comment: Oh Sorry! FireFox Quantum version 60.0.1( 64 bit), But does the driver also effect? I don't know why I am not able to click the button. Maybe because of the ng-click tag?

Comment: Driver version have to be sync with browser other won't work

Comment: ohk, But the browser is opening the site is loading that means drivers are compatible?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. thats why asking for webdriver version

Comment: Sir, the version is 3.9.0 and I am getting this error while clicking the element `Element <a class="external" href=""> could not be scrolled into view `is it because of the ng tag?

Comment: Sir I am on the Latest version

Comment: Yes sir I have upgraded to 3.12 still the same from using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.external')` gives this message `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="be6a6535-7db8-46fa-8a4d-c4ac0b5fe04b", element="0f310fae-ae2e-4987-a5c2-bbae575acd2c")>`

Comment: what is your gecko driver version ?

Comment: geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64

Comment: Is it throwing the same error for CSS Selector and Link text mentioned in my answer.? I noticed that you used a.external

Comment: I used this `elm = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Check it out') driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm)` it worked but instead of landing into amazon it redirects to homepage don't know why any Idea? Page has many check it out buttons all targetting to amazon none of them redirects to the homepage!